# Render to an offscreen framebuffer in metal

Tags: swift, textures, metal, metalkit

I tried to create a output texture & set it to colorattachments[0]
in renderpassDesriptor instead of curentdrawable.texture . In other word scene is rendered into an off-screen framebuffer

```
let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
textureDescriptor.textureType = MTLTextureType.type2DMultisample 
textureDescriptor.width = drawable.texture.width
textureDescriptor.height = drawable.texture.height
textureDescriptor.sampleCount = 4
textureDescriptor.pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
textureDescriptor.storageMode = .private
textureDescriptor.usage = .renderTarget

let sampleTex = device.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor)

let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = sampleTex
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor =
                MTLClearColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store
```

off-screen framebuffer is bound as a texture. So what I need to do is set off-screen framebuffer texture as current darwable texture. That means what I render to off-screen texture, not directly into the screen should appear as current drawable. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't make your texture be the drawable's texture. You just draw your texture to the drawable's texture in a second render pass (but, typically, in the same command buffer).

Comment: how am I suppose to have multiple render pass to same command buffer?Can you please explain with example code?

Comment: You're presumably already using the `renderPassDescriptor` in your code to create a render command encoder. When you end encoding with that command encoder, just reconfigure `renderPassDescriptor` (or create a new one), create a new render command encoder with it, encode additional commands, and end encoding.

Comment: got it.Thank you very much.